# How to generate SQL code representing a db migration?

Tags: sequelize.js, migration, sequelize-cli

Locally, I run `yarn run migrate --name filename.js` to run a specific database migration. In package.json I have:

```
"scripts": {
    "migrate": "tsc && npx sequelize-cli db:migrate",
```

Is there a way to generate the SQL code that captures that migration?
If I have that SQL code, it would make it much easier for me to subsequently run the migration on my production database.